# Cannot resize partition with gparted

Tags: gparted

I have dual boot with Win10/Ubuntu. I am running gparted within Ubuntu. I have also tried running gparted using the live USB. The result is same.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

I would like to increase the size of **/dev/nvme0n1p6** (selected blue) using the unallocated space. But I am not able to do that.

[image]

I wonder if I am doing something wrong. I am also unsure why my unallocated space is split in two.

Comment: inorder to increase.. you should have un-allocated space adjacent to this partition.. either right side or left side of it. you can change p3 or p4 as the un-allocated is in between them.

Comment: Thanks the input. I wouldn't have guessed that the order of the table mattered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have unallocated space adjacent to /dev/nvme0n1p6. If you want to move /dev/nvme0n1p4 then /dev/nvme0n1p5 and then /dev/nvme0n1p6

Comment: I would also like to [change the swap partition or better add a swap file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq)